# Excel 2013 disable Multi-threaded calculation in registry

Tags: multithreading, excel, registry, dword

I have now searched for how I can disable Multi-threaded calculation in the  registry i think it´s in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Options but dont know what to create to disabel it

I tried:
DWORD: DisabelMultiThreadedCalculation
Value: 1 and 0

Anyone got an Idea?

Comment: No i want to shoot it out to a vouple of 100 computers

Answer (score 0):

Thad's answer is correct and can work, however if the workbook opens too fast, I've found that it fails.

> *Thad Murillo wrote:*
>
> *Private Sub Workbook_Open() ' Disable MultiThreaded Calculation '*
> *Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.Enabled = False ' Other options '*
> *' Automatic Mode ' ' Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.ThreadMode =*
> *xlThreadModeAutomatic ' ' Manual Mode ' '*
> *Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.ThreadMode = xlThreadModeManual '*
> *' Use 2 CPU ' ' Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.ThreadCount = 2 '*
> *End Sub*

Add a second line of Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(0:00:05)) or change the 05 to however many seconds you want it to delay and it should delay enough to run on startup. So...

> Private Sub Workbook_Open()
>
> Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
>
> Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.ThreadMode = xlThreadModeManual
> Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.ThreadCount = 4
>
> End Sub

The above worked for one of the users we support, as Excel was trying to use 16 cores and failing. 4 was just fine.  To disable...

> Private Sub Workbook_Open()
>
> Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
>
> Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.Enabled = False
>
> End Sub

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an OLD post, but I have gotten the answer and tested the deployment:
You need to create an excel addin
That addin needs to be placed in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\XLSTART

Users can change the setting if they choose, but each time excel is opened, multi-threaded calculations is disabled.  Also, this can be setup as part of the .msp file for the deployment in systems like Configuration manager

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Disable MultiThreaded Calculation '
    Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.Enabled = False
    
    ' Other options '
    
    ' Automatic Mode '
    ' Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.ThreadMode = xlThreadModeAutomatic '
    
    ' Manual Mode '
    ' Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.ThreadMode = xlThreadModeManual '
    
    ' Use 2 CPU '
    ' Application.MultiThreadedCalculation.ThreadCount = 2 '
End Sub

Comment: That's the porly formatted code.  Works in 2010, 2013, and 2016